# Spring Security thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 isn't working

Tags: templates, spring-security, thymeleaf

header.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

<div th:fragment="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Shop</a>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/item/new">Add Items</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/items">Manage Items</a>
            </li>
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/cart">Cart</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/orders">Buy History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/members/login">Log in</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/members/logout">Log out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" th:action="@{/}" method="get">
                <input name="searchQuery" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

</html>
```

this is my thymeleaf template html file.

Also I added this dependency to build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
```

SecurityConfig.java

```java
package me.jwkwon0817.shop.config;

import me.jwkwon0817.shop.domain.services.MemberService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    MemberService memberService;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin(form -> {
            form.loginPage("/members/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/members/login/error");
            })
            .logout(logout -> {
                logout.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/members/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
            });
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And this is my SecurityConfig file.

But the page shows me all li tags even though the button is only for authenticated user.

I wrote all html file again. But it doesn't work.

I expect that the page shows only "Cart", "Buy History", "Logout" button when the user loginned.
Also the page should show "Login" button when the user logouted.
And the page should show "Add Items", "Manage Items" when the user has ADMIN role.